# Find points with range between two numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a stock chart, and were looking for a way to properly split the price on the x-axis and the date (in milliseconds) on the y-axis.

if I for example have `1000` dates, I can't show them all. But would like to show `10`.

so if I have two dates `1266278400000` and `1477008000000` Is there some function in javascript that can find `10` evenly spread numbers between them?

The same goes for price, but I guess that's pretty much the same.

Comment: why should there be a function? it's s simple math: `increment = (large - small)/buckets`, which gives you an increment you can loop on. bucket 1 = small, bucket 2 = small+increment, bucket 3 = small + (increment * 2), etc...

Comment: Divide the difference of the highest and lowest by 10 to get the interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's as simple as:

```
(high - low) / 10
```

That gets your step size.  Then, loop through adding that step size each iteration.